# Rails, When displaying a number, if 0 or under 10, always show two 00 zeos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have query which returns a count. Regardless of whether is 0 or 4 (anything under 10, I always want the number to display like so:

```
If / Display:
0 / 00
2 / 02
12 / 12
```

IE always with the 00 place holder. Is there a helper method for this or is this a custom job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"%02d" % my_int
```

For documentation, see [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-M000770).